# Busted nVidia graphic card on laptop

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card, motherboard

I've got Inspiron 3442 (i5,500GB,8GB,Intel HD4400/nVidia 820M).

Few weeks back the display went black. So I tried a fresh installation of Windows. It was working fine, until I installed the Intel graphics driver (to install nVidia drivers, Intel drivers must be installed). As soon as the driver got installed the display again went black.
Suspecting a fault with the hardware, I visited the service center and they confirmed it saying the nVidia chip is busted. The resolution they told me is that they'll have to disable the nVidia chip on the motherboard for which they'll charge me approx 26USD.

I saw some articles online to disable the graphic card on laptops, but all were generic and didnt not help me.

So:

1. Is it possible to disable the nVidia card on this specific model through BIOS?

   - If yes, please help with this.
2. I could continue to use the laptop without installing the graphic drivers and using Windows basic drivers and not pay the service center guys.

   - Could that lead to malfunction of other components?
3. Just for curiosity, is it worth trying to disable the nVidia chip on motherboard by myself?
4. The tech guys at service center told me that the cause of damage could've been overheating of the component. I do play games on this laptop occasionally. About 9 months back I noticed that the temperature went up 90°C, soon bought a laptop cooler and never saw temp higher than 70°C after that. - Could that still have caused the issue?

Comment: I wouldn't trust that service if I were you.  Boot up with a linux live system (PartedMagic, Rescatux or any linux installation disk) and see if your graphics hardware is detected.

Comment: Funny thing, that's Dell Service Center.
And I've already got half a mid to fully move to linux now since I was already using ubuntu in dual boot mode earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Go for motherboard replacement thats the only solution if you want to play games on the laptop.

Else disable Nvidia Graphics. Any use laptop for other purposes.

Comment: Well, playing games on this laptop is not a priority anymore, since I'm building a PC. And already tried to google on how to disable the nVidia card, nothing helped me so far.